# How is CodeSpace in V8 heap initialized?

Tags: v8

I'm currently studying V8 source code, basically through hello-world.cc;

In hello-world.cc following steps are executed:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Initialize V8.
  v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
  v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
  std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
  v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
  v8::V8::Initialize(); //1)

  // Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.
  v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
  create_params.array_buffer_allocator =
      v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
  v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params); // 2)reserve memory by mmap
  {
    v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
```

And I also noticed that in Heap::Setup() more detailed areas like newSpace, oldSpace, including CodeSpace are allocated by mmap with PROT_NONE;

My question is,
1)is CodeSpace initialized by mmap, and where is it happened?
2)CodeSpace need PROT_EXEC, where is it set? is it set by mmap or mprotect through allocateRaw?

I went through V8::Initialize(), Heap::Setup(), and could not really get it together

Answer (score 0):

(V8 developer here.) `Heap::SetUp()` calls `CodeRange::EnsureProcessWideCodeRange(...)`. See its implementation in `src/heap/code-range.cc`. (Future readers be aware that these details may well be refactored over time.)

Like other heap memory, code space is initially reserved with `mmap()`, and later `mprotect()` (or the equivalents on other platforms) is used to adjust permissions. Where available, we use fast hardware support (PKU/`pthread_jit_write_protect_np`) for toggling write access.

Comment: Thank you so much for the illustraion.  And I have some more question in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76572174/how-is-codespace-in-v8-heap-initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76572174/how-is-codespace-in-v8-heap-initialized) , If you could pls take a look.