# How is CodeSpace in V8 heap initialized

Tags: v8

Following [How is CodeSpace in V8 heap initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76565039/how-is-codespace-in-v8-heap-initialized)

Thanks for the answer in [How is CodeSpace in V8 heap initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76565039/how-is-codespace-in-v8-heap-initialized), very helpful.

As I studied from the code,

1. In V8::Initialization() process,
   I found a call to the reservation method

```
V8::Initialization()
    --> IsolateAllocator::InitializeOncePerProcess()
        --> GetProcessWidePtrComprCage()->InitReservation(params,existing_reservation)
```

and eventually calls VirtualMemoryCage::InitReservation()

2. In Isolate::New() process,
   I also found a call to the reservation :

```
Isolate::New() 
    --> Isolate::Allocate(false) 
        --> std::make_unique<IsolateAllocator>() 
            --> #if defined(V8_COMPRESS_POINTERS_IN_ISOLATE_CAGE) 
                (isolate_ptr_compr_cage_.InitReservation(params)_
```

3. In Heap::SetUp() I also found a call to the reservation method:

```
Isolate::Init()
    --> Heap::SetUp
    --> CodeRange::EnsureProcessWideCodeRange
        --> code_range->InitReservation(page_allocator, requested_size)
            --> VirtualMemoryCage::InitReservation(params)
                -->reservation()->SetPermissions(reservation()->address(), reserved_area,PageAllocator::kReadWrite)
```

So I'm really confused haha;

My questions are:

1. Which process above is heap initially reserved?
2. heap_.SetUp is called in isolate::Init() method, but where is isolate::Init called? I could not find it.
3. So the CodeSpace is reserved by mmap() and later mprotect() to adjust permissions. I found the mprotect is called in AllocateRaw() method. Does it mean that the adjustion of the CodeSpace's EXEC permission is not done by mmap(), only by AllocateRaw()? Does it mean the exec permission is actually added during allocation operation, not during the initial reservation?

4）And in which scenario is AllocateRaw called?